# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am developing an application  in ASP.NET MVC 5 and using the code first approach.

When I try to enable migration then it is throwing an error. I found already MySQL.Data.dll in references. What could be the issue?

I uploaded the [source here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5isutdeugcm14u/Demo.rar?dl=0).

Error is mentioned below:

```
    enable-migrations -contexttypename SMSContext
    Checking if the context targets an existing database...
    System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
       at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)
       at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
       at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateConnectionFromProviderName(String providerInvariantName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)

    WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
    To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
    Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
    To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

    Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in your web.config:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Version set to 6.9.3.0 but in your bin folder files MySql.Data.dll and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll has version 6.8.3.0

Modify your web config to use proper version or update your dlls from packages folder.

The root of your problem is when you, using nuget, installed MySql.Data.Entities it replaced your newer version of MySql.Data with older, but web config stay unchanged.

Comment: I changed the version 6.8.3.0 in webconfig.

Comment: but this i am getting this exception.

No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Comment: not helped? Then undo your changes and replace file in bin folder for one with correct version

Answer (score 1):

I have the same experience as you.
And I modify the mysql.data Version from the Web.Config of """" to be matched the MySql.Data.dll and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll version.succeed.

```html
 
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.10.6.0" newVersion="6.9.10.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>

 <DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peSSh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the dll under the References in your project. Remove it and add

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).